# Get values from json request in SOAPUI

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I am trying to get value of `TxnType` from json request while mocking a response from SOAPUI. I want to respond with different responses based the value of `TxnType`.

```
{
    "Request": {
        "UserId": "user",
        "TxnType": "fetch"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the groovy script to fetch the request value with **fixed json**

```
def json = """{
    "Request": {
        "UserId": "user",
        "TxnType": "fetch"
    }
}"""

def transactionType = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json).Request.TxnType
log.info "TxnType is : ${transactionType}"
```

You may quickly try the <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5139345048600576)</kbd>

If you want to use the dynamic json in the mock script, then you can use below **mock script dispatcher**

```
def transactionType = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent).Request.TxnType
log.info "TxnType is : ${transactionType}"
```

Answer (score 1):

// Pick Request Body

```
def requestBody = mockRequest.getRequestContent()
log.info "Request body: " + requestBody
```

// Pick TxnType value

```
def txnType = requestBody["TxnType"]
```

(or something like this)